# Stop MySql from auto sorting while inserting

Tags: mysql, sorting, insert

The default syntax of 'insert' statement in MySQL is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...);
```

What I know is this command inserts a new row after the last row present in the table. But i don't know why it is automatically sorting it and insert the new row based on the order.

The **command** i used is:

```
INSERT INTO survey_questions VALUES ("Q6fiMg","Testing1","textbox","","true");
```

**My table structure:-**
[image]

**Query performed and output:-**
[image]

It is not inserting the new row at the last. It is inserting after the row with id(Q4kB3i). My question_id column is just a primary key. I dint apply any kind of sorting on the column.   Can someone explain me why this is happening and how do i stop it?

Comment: primary keys are indices, and indices are ordered by ASC by default.

Comment: In SQL there is no such thing as first or last row without **explicitly** specifying `ORDER BY`. Insert statements knows nothing about what you mean by last row. If you need to show your rows in order they have been inserted you have to have ether an `auto_increment` column (that would be a better choice for `question_id` BTW especially if you use InnoDB) or `datetime/timestamp` column, or both. And then explicitly use `ORDER BY <auto_increment_column>`in your select statement.

Comment: so what is the solution?
Should i be adding a new column `order` to arrange my questions??

Comment: *so what is the solution?* Take a closer look at the answer in my comment. The answer is given.

Comment: i had commented before reading your comment. it was actually for @sebas.
Thank you. thats what i thought.

Comment: BTW while at it consider to **normalize** your data. **Don't** store delimited values in your database.

Comment: Wont it take much more time to retrieve those options from another table?
Currently i use `explode` in php after retrieving the value.

Answer (score -1):

You are not specifying a sort order for your select, so the order in which records are retrieved is undetermined.

If you dont specify the sort order (`ORDER BY ColName [ASC/DESC]`) there is no gaurantee of the order in which records are returned.

The number of factors that can affect this are plent (from Database Engine, Version Number, Indexing, data Paging, the retrieveal algorith, etc)

So in short, if you wish to retrieve the data in a specified order, specify an [ORDER BY clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: when i don't specify a sort order for select. It will retrieve the records as present in the table without arranging any rows. So the last inserted row should be displayed as last row, but it isnt. it means the inserting is being done via sorting, (i guess).

Comment: No Order by, No **GAURANTEED** sort order.

Comment: I wish to sort them by the order in which they where inserted and not by ascending or descending order because my `question_id` is a random string generator. So sorting them would jumble up.

Comment: Then make use of an [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column